# Can I VEVO video embed autoplay?

Tags: html, iframe, video-streaming

I have searched high and low for any VEVO documentation, but there does not seems to be some.

Can VEVO video embeds be instructed to autoplay?

I have guessed several parameters like the one below.

```
<iframe width="575" height="324" src="http://cache.vevo.com/m/html/embed.html?video=GBA320903400" frameborder="0" autoplay="1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: you can check the right settings here: http://blog.marcovalsecchi.it/2014/03/how-to-enable-autoplay-on-vevo-embed.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is possible by adding "&autoplay=1" to the iframe URL.

```
<iframe width="575" height="324" src="http://cache.vevo.com/m/html/embed.html?video=GBA320903400&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can iframe the embed player url, utm content none will hide the vevo logo and skip the ads showing in the player embed code.

now you will need to find the autostop enable...

```
<iframe width='480' height='270' src='http://www.vevo.com/watch/GBA320903400?utm_medium=embed_player&utm_content=none' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen scrolling='No'></iframe>
```